# Why does my function in my custom directive trigger twice upon re-entering a screen?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a custom directive that returns various template files to build survey questions based on their type (select, checkbox etc) but the behaviour of my directive changes based on whether I have already accessed it despite having completely left the url and hopefully destroyed any remnant of it.

Basically changeDate is supposed to run once upon entering the directive (triggered by the setting of tempdate) which should update a label on the template. This actual input element is being hidden. The problem is that if I leave the page that uses this template completely and then go back into it the changeDate function runs twice regardless of what is inside it or what it does.

datepicker.html

```
<div class="question-title q-element"><div>{{question.question[language]}}</div></div>
  <div class="question-response">
    <ng-form  name="innerForm">
        <span>
            <span ng-show="question.response" class="select-label-pos">{{formattedDate}}</span>
            <span ng-show="!question.response" class="select-label-pos">Pick a Date</span>
        </span>
        <input ng-change="changeDate()" ng-required="{{question.mandatory}}" ng-model="tempdate"  type="date">
    </ng-form>
</div>
```

inputDirective.js

```
(function(){
    "use strict";
    angular.module('gather.directives.inputDirective',
        [

        ]).directive('inputDirective',
        [
             function(){


                return {


                    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

                        scope.language = attrs.language;
                        if(attrs.inputDirective==="datepicker"){

                            var first = true;
                            if(attrs.draft==='false') {
                                //console.log('not a draft, setting default date');
                                scope.tempdate = new Date(1999, 3, 3);
                            }else{
                                scope.tempdate = new Date(scope.question.response);
                                //console.log('got a draft, getting response date');
                            }
                            console.log('Running Datepicker, the response is ', scope.question.response);

                            scope.logOut = function(){
                                console.log('BUILDING TEMPLATE');
                                console.log(scope.question.qid);
                            };


                            scope.changeDate = function(){
                               // console.log('first: ',first);
                                //console.log('attrs.draft: ', attrs.draft);
                                if(first===true&&attrs.draft==='false'){
                                    //if its the first time and not a draft just flip the switch
                                    first = false;
                                    //console.log('Not a draft, first load/change: Just flip the switch');
                                    //console.log(scope.question);
                                }else if(attrs.draft==='true'){
                                    //if draft is true we will already have a value, set the tempdate abd update the label
                                    attrs.draft = 'false';
                                    first = false;
                                    var d = new Date(scope.question.response);
                                    scope.day = d.getDate();
                                    scope.month = d.getMonth()+1;
                                    scope.year = d.getFullYear();
                                    scope.formattedDate = scope.month + '-'+scope.day+'-'+scope.year;
                                    //console.log('Survey is a draft: Update the datepicker label with the response');
                                } else{
                                    //if its not the first time and draft is false we start normal updates of the values
                                    var d = new Date(scope.tempdate);
                                    scope.day = d.getDate();
                                    scope.month = d.getMonth()+1;
                                    scope.year = d.getFullYear();
                                    scope.formattedDate = scope.month + '-'+scope.day+'-'+scope.year;
                                    scope.question.response = scope.tempdate;
                                    //console.log('Not a draft, not first change/load: Update the datepicker label with the response');
                                }

                            };
                        }


                    },
                    templateUrl: function(elem, attrs, scope){
                        console.log();
                        return "views/question-types/"+attrs.inputDirective+"-question.html";
                    },

                };
        }]
    );
```

survey.html

```
<a id="top"></a>
    <div id="survey" class="snap-container">
        <div id="header">
            <h1>Capture Data </h1>
            <a href="#/home">
                <div class="home-button">
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="menu-button" snap-toggle="right">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="surveys-container">
            <div id="template" ng-repeat="asset in template | filter:{type:'html'}">

                <ng-include src="addAssetPath(asset.path)"></ng-include>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="currentGroup == false" class="groupMenu overlay-view">
                <h2  class="group-title">Lead Capture</h2>
                <div ng-repeat="group in survey.groups|orderBy:'group_order'" >
                    <div  ng-click="changeGroup(group.group_name.en)" class=" menu-group-title">

                        <span>{{group.group_name.en}}</span>

                        <span ng-if="group.group_name.en != 'Barcode'" class="arrow-icon ui-icon"></span>
                        <span ng-if="group.group_name.en == 'Barcode'" class="scan-icon ui-icon"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="action-button client-gradient-submit" ng-click="submitForm()">Submit</button>
                <button class="action-button client-gradient-draft" ng-click="saveDraft()">Save</button>
            </div>
            <div ng-show="currentGroup == group.group_name.en"  class="group group-container overlay-view" ng-repeat="group in survey.groups|orderBy:'group_order'">
                {{logTest(group.group_name.en, $index)}}
                <h2  class="group-title">{{group.group_name.en}}</h2>
                <div class=" question-container {{question.css_class.en}}" ng-repeat="question in group.questions|orderBy:'question_order'">

                    <div class="" ng-switch="question.type">
                        <div input-directive="text" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}"  ng-switch-when="S">

                        </div>
                        <div input-directive="select" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}" ng-switch-when="!">

                        </div>
                        <div input-directive="radio" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}" ng-switch-when="L">

                        </div>
                        <div input-directive="textarea" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}" ng-switch-when="T">

                        </div>
                        <div input-directive="checkbox" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}" ng-switch-when="M">

                        </div>
                        <div input-directive="datepicker" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}" ng-switch-when="D">

                        </div>
                        <div input-directive="other" question="question" language="{{surveyLang}}" draft="{{draft}}" ng-switch-default>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button class="done-button" ng-click="changeGroup(false)" ng-show="currentGroup != false">Done</button>

            </div>


        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: I have the same Probleme, did you find a solution ?